# Most Pythonic way for creating a defaultdictionary counter

Tags: python

I am trying to count occurrences of various items based on condition. What I have until now is this function that given two items will increase the counter like this:

given `[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a')]` will `output defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {'a': Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 1}), 'b': Counter({'a': 1})`

the function can be seen bellow

```
def freq(samples=None):
    out = defaultdict(Counter)
    if samples:
        for (c, s) in samples:
            out[c][s] += 1
    return out
```

It is limited though to only work with tuples while I would like it to be more generic and work with any number of variables e.g., `[('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'a')]` would still work and I would be able to query the result for lets say `res['a']['b']` and get the count for `'c'` that is one.

What would be the best way to do this in Python?

Comment: What's wrong with using a tuple such as `('a', 'a')` as the key on a Counter?! Otherwise, arbitrary nesting isn't going to work, or how would you handle both `('a', 'b')` and `('a', 'b', 'c')` where `out['a']` should be both counter and a default dict for nested items

Comment: you mean when I encounter `('a', 'a', 'b')` I remove the last value and make the remaining a tuple? the thing is that the first key `a`in this case might have a number of subkeys that they in turn might have a number of subkeys too.  I need to be able to reach each final value, something like a DAG imagine. Plus I don't want to go from two values to three, but dynamically deal with any number of values.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala regarding your edited comment, if you notice the examples they are either groups of two or three items, there is no way you would see (a, a), (a, b, t).

Comment: The problem with your question right now is that it just says: "While I won't describe X, here is Y which is not quite X and X is something else. So, what is the best way to do X"

Comment: You should read more carefully the question in that case. I am giving an example of exactly what I want only that it is limited in only having a depth of 2, and asking for a proper way of dealing with more elements, again maybe imagining it like a b+ tree would help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all tuples in the list have the same length:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
def freq(samples=[]):
    sorted_samples = sorted(samples)
    if sorted_samples and len(sorted_samples[0]) > 2:
        return {key: freq(value[1:] for value in values) for key, values in groupby(sorted_samples, itemgetter(0))}
    else:
        return {key: Counter(value[1] for value in values) for key, values in groupby(sorted_samples, itemgetter(0))}
```

That gives:

```
freq([('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('a', 'c')])
>>> {'a': Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}), 'b': Counter({'a': 1})}

freq([('a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'c')])
>>> {'a': {'a': Counter({'a': 1}), 'b': Counter({'c': 1}), 'c': Counter({'c': 1})}, 'b': {'a': Counter({'a': 1})}}
```

Comment: Nice recursive solution :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty sure it could be improved even further (removing the condition and having 1 single return) but my head aches too much ATM ;)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the full tuples as keys

```
def freq(samples=[]):
    out = Counter()
    for sample in samples:
         out[sample] += 1
    return out
```

which would then return things as

```
Counter({('a', 'a', 'b'): 1, ('a', 'b', 'c'): 1, ('b', 'a', 'a'): 1})
```

You could convert the tuples to strings to select certain slices, e.g. `"('a', 'b',"`. For example in a new dictionary `{k: v for k,v in out.items() if str(k)[:10] == "('a', 'b',"}`.

If the groups are indeed either 2 or 3 long, but never both, you can change to:

```
def freq(samples):
    l = len(samples[0])
    if l == 2:
        out = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
        for a, b in samples:
             out[a][b] += 1
    elif l == 3:
        out = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: 0))
        for a, b, c in samples:
            out[a][b][c] += 1
    return out
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I am asking, I clearly state that I need a Pythonic way of dealing with an **arbitrary** number of variables, not just the easily countable 2 and 3. Also your code below and you statement about Antti's comment are not consistent with each other and very different in logic.

Comment: Ok, apparently misunderstood. Removed the reference.

Comment: @Roelant thanks for trying in any case, it seems that this is more complex than I thought and even Guillaumes' answer wont do. It is perfectly correct as far the question has to do though.